# MySQL (mariaDB) I want to aggregate my Select results, where all columns but one are equal and the none equal column is CONCAT_WS into a single value

Tags: mysql, select, concat-ws

I have several occurrences of rows returned from a left join query with all columns being equal except one. These columns will be in sequential order.

The column that is not equal I want to aggregate into a single value using CONCAT_WS and only have one row in the output result for the rows which are equal except for the one I wish to aggregate.

I can do this with a PHP script, but I wondered if it was possible with an SQL statement

I am using mariaDB as my mySQL server

example

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5

aa      bb      cc      dog     dd
aa      bb      cc      cat     dd
aa      bb      cc      pig     dd
aa      bb      cc      monkey  dd
aa      bb      cc      bear    dd
```

I want to get a single result for those records as follows.  From the select queries there will be many blocks of these styled records and also single unique value rows.

```
col1    col2    col3    col4                            col5
aa      bb      cc      dog,cat,pig,monkey,bear         dd
```

using CONACAT_WS(",", rec1.col4, rec2.col4, rec3.col4,rec4.col4,rec5.col4)

Is the above possible with just SQL ?

It seems like a likely scenario, that other people might have wanted to do.

There may be a technical term for what I want to do, but I do not know it.

Thanks

mcl

Comment: Read about GROUP_CONCAT(): https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I think GROUP_CONCAT() could be the answer - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding "group by col1" this will aggregate in a single row every record having the same value in that column

Comment: Not got access to the Database at the moment, will try next week - thanks for your suggestion - seems logical.